# Would anyone know of a good easy connect flooring that would work on a slope?

Tags: flooring

I'm working on replacing the flooring in a basketball arcade game but it's difficult with the way its built. Its original floor is basically a big thick tarp stretched making it slope. We tried using vinyl boards with these plastic thin connectors and they did not last long.
I'm looking for some type of easy connect flooring like the vinyl but more durable (aka have basketballs fall on them and not disconnect) and can be built on a slope on top of the tarp. I am an arcade technician so this is a bit out of my field and would appreciate any ideas or advice.

[image: The game in question]

Comment: Sheet vinyl over some 1/4" or 3/8" plywood?  Do you have to be able to walk on the surface?

Comment: yes at least needs to be able to support one person. also trying to consider noise from basketballs coming down. I'm currently looking at a soft tile like they use for yoga areas.

Comment: I just looked up sheet vinyl and found a rubber one that may work. thank you

Comment: a tatami mat could work

Comment: Some kind of glue-down LVP?